# Problem with create-react-app, It takes too long, what is the solution?

Tags: npm

[image: 1]

I want to run create-react-app but it has been stuck like this for more than 5 hours

I deleted node js and downloaded other versions, however, the same problem

Answer (score 1):

React has recently migrated their documentation website from https://reactjs.org/ to https://react.dev/, which means that all the previous references and guides have been redirected to the new website. However, I've noticed that there's currently no documentation available for the new create-react-app.

If you're looking to develop a React application, I would suggest considering using [vitejs.dev](https://vitejs.dev/) instead of create-react-app. Vite is a modern build tool that supports various frameworks, including React and Vue. It's much easier to use and won't affect your learning process as the code structure is almost identical.

It's always important to stay up-to-date with the latest tools and resources available in the React ecosystem as a developer. By utilizing the most effective and efficient tools available, you can significantly improve your development process and productivity.